# How to Enter Map Coordinates

Tags: qgis

I am new to QGIS.  I have a map with known coordinate points.  How can I manually enter these points and then export this map as a .tfw??

Comment: how many points are you talking about?

Comment: If you have a map with coordinate points, can you just import it to your new map or do you just have a paper copy? Do you have the points on a spreadsheet?

Comment: Background info: I have a hand-drawn contour map with 4 known points.  It is saved as a tiff.  I need to geo-ref this map, save it as a .tfw.  I then need to import this file into Kingdom (seimic interpretation software)

Comment: Where I am at: Raster/Georeferencer/Open Raster/Choose Coordinate System/Add Points/Enter Map coordinates.   So I have my map in Georeferencer with 4 red dots - What do I do next?  How do I get this to export as a .tfw so I can import it into my other software?

Comment: Thank you, but the 2 answers did not help.  After use the transformation settings button and I hit the green "start  georeferencing" triangle, how do I save/export this as a tfw?  I can only use a tfw in the program that I am importing into.  Please help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

First create an empty shapefile in QGIS from the menu bar: Layer > Create Layer > New Shapefile Layer. Create fields to hold the information about the points you're going to add.

Then the plugin I would recommend for adding single points (ie. not TOO many) is called **NumericalDigitize**.

Once installed and in an edit session you'll end up with a little button like this on the end of your editing toolbar:

[image]

...and it will allow you to  add a feature by the X and Y coordinates you have:

[image]

Finally to save the map, you can create a quick export by going to **Project (menu) > Save as Image** and choose the TIF format.

This will save a TIF file with an associated .tifw file, which is the georeferencing information.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the points in a spreadsheet, you can use the [Add Delimited Text](http://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-add-x-and-y-coordinates-from-a-spreadsheet) tool in QGIS.